# Suggestions on board designing, ground plane and layers - PCB images

Tags: pcb-design, noise, eaglecad, solenoid, pcb-layers

I'm designing a board (with *EAGLE*) for my first time and, before posting here, I've read some topics and documents on how to design a board, but I still need help since I'm a beginner.

My board should power and control 9 solenoids (12V, 2A) and a servo.
I will use a board with **two layers** and **90um**.

Two proportional solenoids use PWM at 120Hz.
The oscillator for atmega328p is 16Mhz.

The board is **powered by 12VDC** with 12VDC, 200Ah AGM battery and I'm using an **isolated power supply (+5VDC)** to power up the microcontroller (atmega328p). The atmega328p isolation is made by optocouplers which drive the MOSFETs.

This is the [schematics](http://www.skeetty.com/schematics-correct.png) made in Eagle where **GND5 is the ground for the 12V** circuit and **GND is the ground for 5V system** 
*(sorry if the schematics is not very clear, EAGLE does not allow me to remove some junction points)*.

I don't know if **I need to create two ground planes** (one for GND5 and another one for the GND) or if **I only need to create a ground plane** for the GND5.
The +5V system powers only the atmega328p and a RC receiver, may be, it does not need a GND plane? So I can only create the GND5 plane?

It is *better* to put only the ground plane on a layer and all the other connections traces and +12V traces on the other layer?

Could it be a good idea to create a "+12V plane"?
What are your suggestions for the designing of this board?

I'm following these guidelines:

- place the decoupling capacitors C22, C23 very close to the microcontroller
- place filter capacitors close to the drivers (MCP1406)
- place diodes close to the connectors for the solenoids P_OUTx
- large traces for +12V (or a +12 plane??)
- only GND5 ground plane (??)

[**EDIT:** The schematics is now correct and clearer]

[image]

---

**EDIT1:** 
These are the [board layout](http://www.skeetty.com/board01.png), the [upper](http://www.skeetty.com/bottom.png) and the [bottom](http://www.skeetty.com/up.png) layout.
I placed a ground plane for GND5 (the ground for 12V) and a power plane for +12V. Do you think it is better to place also a ground plane for 5V?

[image]
[image]
[image]

---

### **EDIT2:**

This is the second version of the layout. I separated the 5V circuit from the 12V circuit by using the optoisolator and the isolated power supply as a "moat".
I also placed the ground plane for 12V at the bottom layer and the ground plane for the 5V circuit on the upper layer.
Is it OK, now?

[image]
[image]
[image]

---

### **EDIT3**

This is the third version of the board layout. I removed the +12V connector which was at the bottom of the board since it wasn't really useful and I tried to separate the two circuits (12V, 5V) in a better way.
I also fixed the errors with some traces which were connected to a wrong source.
Are they Ok, now? Anything to fix?

[image]
[image]
[image]

---

### **EDIT4**

This is the version #4 for my board layout as suggested by @ThreePhaseEel. Now, I think all the traces are in the correct area and the optocouplers work as a "barrier" between the two circuits. I hope everthing is Ok, now! :)

[image]
[image]
[image]

**

### VERSION WITH MOUNTING HOLES

**
[image]

---

### **EDIT5**

This is the version #5 with the diodes flipped and wider traces for the diodes.
I also tried to remove the acute trace for the 12V connector.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't really understand why you have 3 grounds and mixing them: for instance C16 and C17 are grounded to GND5 and connected to +12V and on the same part, C15 is grounded to GND-12.  I think GND5 = GND-12 but please review your grounding and and study if you really need to isolate your powers. For the layout the best is to make a first try and then we will comment and help you to improve your work. Giving general statements doesn't make the layout as everyone understand and design his own way.

Comment: Thank you, zeqL. I'm going to finish my first layout and I'll post it. I nthe schematics there is a typo: GND-12 is GND5, so I just have two different grounds. Sorry for the mistake. I'm going to post the layout in few hours.

Comment: @zeqL, I added the PCB layout with ground plane (for 12V), power plane (for 12V).

Comment: I don't know if it is better to add a ground plane for GND(5V) in order to have a plane behind the oscillator, too, or if I don't need it since the 5V system is isolated.

Comment: Very confusing for the ground for +12V to be called GND5.  Why not call it GND12?  Also, the schematic is not drawn very well.  You've got extra connections (colored dots) shpwing up all over the place, like the second on near near C13, C8 etc., and all of the ones where a net is connected to a component (D5, virtually all the other diodes, resistors and caps).  Usually this means overlapping nets.  In any case, it is not a properly drawn schematic.  Do an electrical rule check (ERC),

Comment: Thank you for your answer. EAGLE doesn't show errors and unfortunately does not allow me to remove the junction dots.

Comment: I don't know if it is a problem with the mac osx eagle version.. but the conjuction dots cannot be removed easily

Comment: No mounting holes? Always a good practise

Comment: If you rotate the diodes connected to the solenoid connectors 180º tracks will be shorter and that will improve the diode performance. As well, you can make those tracks a bit wider, plenty of room and not harm.

Comment: There is an acute angle close to the 12 V connector on bottom layer. Usually acute angles are avoided. (This could be a controversial point). Anyway, i think you can redesign a bit nicer without a acute angle

Comment: I totally forgot the mounting holes! Thank you for the tip!! I also flipped the diode in version #5 and a tried to remove the acute angle as you suggested. I hope now it looks better.. what do you think?

Comment: ok. Just for readibility of the SCH. "GND5" is GND for 12V ? This sounds confusing. I'll suggest "GND" for digital/5V circuit and "GND_Power" for the other GND. Or something like this.

Comment: I added the schematics with the GND_PWR as ground for the 12V circuit. I hope now is more clear to read. Any other suggestions? :)

Comment: Don't forget to organize the silkscreen labels after your layout is done. Takes a lot of work but its worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I never did this kind of stuff, but I'm going to learn about silkscreen and labels in Eagle since I think they are very useful to understand the correct meaning of each connector or trace on the PCB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, what you want to do is *split the planes* -- your 5V power grid/net and ground plane are exclusively in the digital logic section of the board, while the 12V power grid/net and ground plane are exclusively in the power section of the board.  This means that there is a *copper-free* "moat" between the two sections of the board -- the only things that span the moat are the optocouplers and the isolated 5V supply "brick" module.

Comment: So I should change the position of the atmega in order to divide better the planes?

Comment: You'll probably have to rearrange the whole board -- start with the parts on the "moat" so to speak.

Comment: @MarcusBarnet -- it's a copper-free region that completely separates the 12V and 5V sections of the board

Comment: Huh? What you want is a region of PCB that has *no copper whatsoever on it* -- no tracks or planes run there.

Comment: The optoisolators have one side in the 5v/digital region and their other side in the 12v/power region

Comment: I added the second version of the layout and I used your suggestions to improve it. What do you think, now? Do you think is it OK? I phisically separated the two circuits and the ground planes. I also placed the 12V ground plane in a different layer..

Comment: You have the parts placed correctly now -- however, there are several traces that breach the isolation barrier.  It looks like you have some things on the board connected to the wrong return/ground...

Comment: The trace connecting R49 to PC4 is a start.  Also, RC12 looks to be on the wrong side of the board altogether (it should be on the 12V side of the board), and the cathodes of OK1-OK4 are connected to a trace on the 12V side of the board...

Comment: I added the third version of the layout. Thanks to your suggestions, I fixed the problem with the OK1-OK4 cathodes and I removed the 12V connector since it wasn't useful for this board. I hope now everything is OK. What do you think? Thank you!

Comment: Last but not least, the traces from R40 and R46 to ZU4 can be rerouted to be not under the optocouplers, and the same can be done for the power trace from IC2 to OK1-OK4.  Flip the trace from OK11 to OK12 onto the other side so it can be moved out from under the optos, and pull the planes back so they terminate at the edge of the optocouplers, and then you're done, at least with making the moat I described earlier. :)

Comment: I added the version #4 of my layout. I followed all your advices! I hope now it is OK. I learnt a lot thanks to this topic and to you! I've very happy since I'm learning new stuff every day!

Comment: do you think version #4 is better than the version #3? I flipped the diode and I places a restricted area around the optocouplers section to avoid traces near the isolation zone..

Comment: Version 5 looks great :) Glad we were able to help!

Answer (score 1):

I use mixed MCU and circuits powered from different sources but I always use a common ground.

Here is a [links](http://www.arduino.org/products/shields/arduino-4-relays-shield) to 'official' Arduino relay product with the [schematics](http://download.arduino.org/products/4RELAYSSHIELD/Arduino-4-Relays-Shield-V1.pdf). And also other documentation : http://download.arduino.org/products/4RELAYSSHIELD/Arduino-4-Relays-Shield-V1_rd.zip

> Why reinvent the wheel? Imitation (copying) is the sincerest form of
>   flattery.
>
> (Charles Caleb Colton)

Comment: You simply *cannot* pass PWM through relays. They are slow and will fail fast due to high switching rates and their mechanical nature. Though they probably will stay somewhere in mid-contact, which may or may not be an actual contact for the solenoid, and thus won't result in the desired effect.